# Unbiased random range generator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, range, generator

To prevent bias for **max**, I'm recalculating each time the decimal range falls above **max**, instead of stripping decimals. Using **random()** introduces some bias I think, but that is acceptable.

Optional arg **decimal** is an integer denoting how many decimal places to include.

Optional arg **exclude** is handy for excluding a specific number (typically 0) from the result.

Optionally returns true or false randomly if all args are omitted.

Basically, I'm just wondering if there's any way to increase the speed and efficiency without adding and more bias (or even reducing bias). It seems the while loops might slow it down. I'm using this for animation, and don't want biased results (especially over small ranges like 1.0 to 2.0).

```
function random(min, max, decimal, exclude) {
    if (min == null) return (Math.random()*2 >= 1) ? true : false
    var decimal = (decimal == null) ? 1 : Math.pow(10,decimal), result = exclude
    while (result == exclude) {
        result = max+1
        while (result > max) var result = Math.round((Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)*decimal)/decimal
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Assuming the distribution is uniform stripping decimals or rounding in a consistent manner shouldn't affect it.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve that `Math.random()` combined with some range math doesn't do for you?

Comment: Stripping decimals (using the typical Math.floor()), in a range from 1 to 2, would mean that all values from 2.0 to 2.999 would return 2. That would favor 2 over any other possible value. I'm not sure if round() adds any bias at all, but I'm not concerned with it.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm just concerned that the added overhead of the while loops may be inefficient. So I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient method, or if this is as good as it gets

Comment: The second while loop can be avoided entirely with proper scaling of the random number.

Comment: @jfriend00, how would I scale it differently to have min and max both be inclusive in the result, but not including any numbers that fall outside of the range?

Comment: Mikke's answer shows you how you scale a random number to be between a min and max: `var rand = (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit cleaner implementation:

```
function random(min, max, decimal, exclude) {
    // if no min and max is passed, return true or false
    if (arguments.length < 2) return(Math.random() >= 0.5);

    // calc decimal multiplier
    var factor = 1, result;
    if (typeof decimal === "number") {
        factor = Math.pow(10, decimal);
    }

    // loop until we get a value that isn't our exclude value
    do {
        // calc rand value in proper range
        result = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

        // adjust to proper number of decimal digits
        result = Math.round(result * factor) / factor;
    } while (result === exclude);
    return result;
}
```

Working demo with decimals: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/SjgaW/

Working demo as integers (with exclude value): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GgkJv/

Changes:

1. Change `decimal` local variable to not be same name as argument so the argument will work
2. Remove one while loop by using proper range scaling
3. Change to do/while so condition isn't tested until after the calculation
4. Use `===` to avoid type conversions
5. Remove multiplication and ternary operator from true/false calculation since the comparison already returns true/false
6. More explicit checking of arguments that doesn't require them to be passed or rely on type conversions to `null`
7. Add relevant comments

Comment: I wish I could of chose both yours and Mikke's (for helping me with the logic part), but I had to choose this because it does what I wanted; it's more efficient. Thank you. I'm a recently self taught newbie, so examples like this help me develop a better coding style

Answer (score 1):

The distribution is uniform, so instead of repeating if the number falls outside your range, you can scale/move the pseudorandom number.

```
var rand = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
```

That removes one of your while loops, and should speed up the code.

Comment: My understanding, given a range of 1 through 2:   2 - 1 == 1,  Math.random() *1 == 0 through 0.99999,  0.99999 + 1 == 1.99999.  Then, 2 is not included in the result.

Comment: You are right in that Math.random() returns a number in the range [0, 1), that is, it never returns 1 (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). However, JavaScript has a number representation with large precision, so the bias we introduce by regarding the exclusive range as inclusive is very low (in other words: if your range is 1-2, the chance of returning a "perfect" 2 is very low)

Comment: Yes, it is very low. Considering I'll never use rounding past random()'s precision, then my max will actually always fall in the range. I won't miss the 0.00000000000001 bias working against a natural 2. Thanks for helping me to see it in that context

Comment: To rephrase: I hadn't realized that after adding round() to my function, that it actually fixed the issue of max being included, so long as I don't ask for a number with decimals exceeding random()'s precision. And it won't affect any bias for my intended use.

Comment: @GabrielHansen Don't use Math.round() -- use Math.floor(), and increase the "max" by 1, instead. If you use Math.round(), then the values at the min and max only have 0.5 range of float-values that map to them, rather than a full 1.0. (maybe I'm misunderstanding your use case however...)